# Buscar dato de json con jquery con su clave y obtener valor

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

Hola estoy tratando de obtener un valor de un json

```
var datos_tipo = {"1":"20G1","2":"25G0","3":"20R1","4":"25R1","5":"42R1"}
```

Tengo esto en mi script y en un select tengo las claves y cuando el usuario selecciona una opcion ya obtengo el value pero no se como hacer para que ese value se busque en ese array.

Este es mi HTML

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <label for="rango">Rango</label>
            <select class="form-control rango" name="rango">
                <option hidden selected>Seleccionar...</option>
                @foreach($rango $elt => $idtipo)
                    <option value="{{$idtipo}}">{{$elt}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <label for="id_tipo">Tipo</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control tipo" name="tipo_tipo" id="id_tipo" readonly>
        </div>
```

Y el Jquery que uso para obtener cual tiene seleccionado el usuario y asi con ese quiero ir a buscar en el array

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            var datos_tipo = {{$codigo_tipo}} //Aqui esta el array
            $("select.rango").change(function(){
                var rango_selec = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
                console.log(rango_selec);
            });
        });
```

Alguna idea de como lo podria realizar?

Gracias

Comment: Agrega tu HTML y lo que lleves al momento por favor

Comment: Ya lo he agregado gracias.

Comment: Sera que al momento de asignar esos datos la variable ya tendrá el contenido??, no se si laravel haría esa asignación síncronamente, yo creo que no... es mas, nisiquiera se si se podria mezclar laravel directamente con javascript...

Comment: Por cierto eso que tienes ahi no es un arreglo, es un objeto, de hecho deberias considerar pasar ese objeto que tienes a un arreglo de informacion, es mucho mas comodo, ya que los indices numericos serian automaticos, mientras que en ese objeto no se como los asignes desde el backend, pero no creo que sea optimo usar los objetos asi con indices numericos...

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario por ahora estan asi numericos,  si tengo un objeto alli consegui acceder con la misma variable y obteniendo eso su contenido datos_tipo [key]

Comment: Esque el problema es que esa tabla contiene el id, tipo, rango
El select contenida id y tipo
y el objeto puse id y rango para que cuando seleccionara el usuario un tipo iria a buscar el id y asi botenia el rango y lo colocaba en ese input

Comment: Probaste la función [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/find) de JavaScript? ;)

Comment: Gracias implementare esa funcion